# Comparing date inside if command in SHELL

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

I was trying to run the following shell script in linux, but for some reason, it is not running properly, I am getting the output of `no` even when the date matches. Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?

```
var='date +%d'
if [ $var = 17 ]
then echo yes
else echo no
fi
```

I am trying to create an automated system based on the date of the month.

Comment: Don't change your question, i.e. the code.

Comment: @Greenonline That was a mistake on my part. My code was not running with $ in it. I just accidentally omitted it while typing it here. Guessed I should copy the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `var='date +%d'` you're essentialy assigning the string `date +%d` to `$var`.

What you probably wanted to do instead, is assign the result of `date +%d` to `$var` via *command substitution*:

```sh
var=$(date +%d)
if [ $var = 17 ]
then echo yes
else echo no
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

1. You aren't accessing the variable correctly - you need a `$` prefix;
2. You are using single quotes not backticks,  when assigning `var` with the return value of the command;
3. You are comparing strings (`=`), not integers (`-eq`).

```
var=`date +%d`
if [ $var -eq 17 ]
then echo yes
else echo no
fi
```

---

#### Updated answer

Taking in Glenn's comments ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/1687951/comparing-date-inside-if-command-in-shell/1687953#comment2593866_1687953), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1687951/comparing-date-inside-if-command-in-shell/1687953#comment2593869_1687953))

1. n/a
2. `${...}` can be considered better than backticks, for reabability and clarity
3. Use `date '+%-d'` to avoid zero padding of the date, for arithmetic comparison,  which will result in *invalid octal number* errors.

Therefore, the same bit of code is, arguably, better written as:

```
var=${date '+%-d'}
if [ $var -eq 17 ]
then echo yes
else echo no
fi
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Yep, I needed my glasses  :-)

Comment: 2. This is one reason why `$(...)` is better than backticks

Comment: 3. Be careful with arithmetic comparison: when the day is the 8th or 9th, `date +%d` returns `08` or `09`, and using that value in an arithmetic expression will result in "invalid octal number" errors. use `date '+%-d'` so the date is not zero-padded.